# converting a csv into date to create a graph

Tags: javascript

I am trying to import a csv file using JavaScript and creating a graph to correspond to that data.
currently, I have imported the csv file but when I'm trying to use date as a parameter to change the graph its not working as the date hasn't been converted to milliseconds yet. and I cant seem to work it out.

not sure if this is duplicated but I did look at this post but didn't have a clue what i am looking at. I am fairly new to JavaScript.

this is my code so far,

this is the data in csv
2022-08-13,2119
2022-08-14,2163
2022-08-15,2171
2022-08-16,2191
2022-08-17,2205
2022-08-18,2205
2022-08-19,2231
2022-08-20,2244
2022-08-21,2244
2022-08-22,2249
2022-08-23,2256

```js
// global variable
getNumbDocMonth();
const years = [];
const values = [];
console.log(years);

// setup

const DATE = [
  "2022-08-16",
  "2022-08-17",
  "2022-08-18",
  "2022-08-19",
  "2022-08-20",
  "2022-08-21",
  "2022-08-22",
  "2022-08-23",
];

// console.log(DATES);

const datapoints = [18, 12, 6, 9, 12, 3, 9];
const convertedDates = DATE.map((date) =>
  new Date(date).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)
);
console.log(convertedDates);

// console.log(datapoints);
const data = {
  labels: DATE,
  datasets: [{
    label: "Global Document Tracker",
    data: datapoints,
    backgroundColor: ["rgba(255, 26, 104, 0.2)"],
    borderWidth: 1,
  }, ],
};

// console.log(data.labels);
// config
const config = {
  type: "bar",
  data,
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: {
        type: "time",
        time: {
          unit: "day",
        },
      },
      y: {
        beginAtZero: true,
      },
    },
  },
};

// render init block
const myChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart"), config);

function filterDate() {
  const start1 = new Date(document.getElementById("start").value);
  const start = start1.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0); //converting to ms

  const end1 = new Date(document.getElementById("end").value);
  const end = end1.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

  const filteredDates = convertedDates.filter(
    (date) => date >= start && date <= end
  );

  myChart.config.data.labels = filteredDates;

  const startArray = convertedDates.indexOf(filteredDates[0]);
  const endArray = convertedDates.indexOf(
    filteredDates[filteredDates.length - 1]
  );

  const copydatapoints = [...datapoints];
  copydatapoints.splice(endArray + 1, filteredDates.length);
  copydatapoints.splice(0, startArray);
  // console.log(copydatapoints);
  myChart.config.data.datasets[0].data = copydatapoints;
  myChart.update();
}

function resetDate() {
  myChart.config.data.labels = convertedDates;
  myChart.config.data.datasets[0].data = datapoints;

  myChart.update();
}

async function getNumbDocMonth() {
  const response = await fetch("Stats_Docs_Total_By_Day.csv");
  const data = await response.text();
  // console.log(data);
  const table = data.split("\n").slice(0);
  // console.log(table);
  table.forEach((row) => {
    const columns = row.split(",");
    const year = columns[0];
    const totalDocCount = columns[1];
    years.push(year);
    // console.log(year, totalDocCount);
  });
}
// END OF BAR CHART DOC PER MONTH
```

```html
<div class="chartMenu"></div>
<div class="chartCard">
  <div class="chartBox">
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas> Start:
    <input id="start" type="date" value="2022-08-15" /> End:

    <input id="end" type="date" value="2022-08-21" />
    <button onclick="filterDate()">Filter</button>
    <button onclick="resetDate()">Reset</button>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-date-fns/dist/chartjs-adapter-date-fns.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your question is specifically to convert the date into milliseconds which you can do using [.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

```
const d = Date.parse("2022-08-16");
console.log(d); //1660608000000
```

Comment: im trying to convert string array into date array, is that possible with this? using,                                       const convertedDatefromCSV = years.parse() ?? but thast not converting whole array